# Display Country of Manufacturer on Category Page Navigation Filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

When we add a product from Admin. We have field "Country of Manufacturer".

Would like to display that as Navigation Filter on Frontend.

[image]

From `Admin -> Product Attribute` By Inspect Element, able to Save Use In Search, but for "Use in Layered Navigation" & "Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" it keep resetting value.

Then i tried to manage using Table.

`SELECT * FROM magento.catalog_eav_attribute;`

For `attribute_id` = `111`.

I have set

```
is_visible
is_searchable
is_filterable
is_comparable
is_visible_on_front
is_html_allowed_on_front
is_filterable_in_search
used_in_product_listing
is_visible_in_advanced_search
is_used_in_grid
is_visible_in_grid
```

to 1. So now my backend `country_of_manufacuter' looks OK on Admin Side, But Frontend side still it's not displaying.

Have done Indexing, Clear Cache as Well.

[image]

How to achieve this? How to display Weight as Well?

Comment: What type of attribute is this? you can only use dropdown, multiple select and price types for layered navigation

Comment: It's Dropdown. It's Magento Default

Comment: If you want to display any attribute(dropdown type) in navigation you have to set Use in Layered Navigation => yes.But you can't edit its value.